# Последовательные ajax запросы

Tags: javascript, ajax

Прошу помощи связывании в последовательном связывании ajax запросов.(пример ниже работает некорректно). Правильная последовательность 1-2-3-4.

HTML:

```
<div id="1" data-loader="../components/header.html"></div>
<div id="2" data-loader="../components/navigation.html"></div>
<div id="3" data-loader="../components/body.html"></div>
<div id="4" data-loader="../components/footer.html"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var url;
var id;
var j=1;


$(document).ready(function () {
$('div[data-loader]').each(function() {
    url=$(this).attr("data-loader");
    id=$(this).attr("id");  
         $.get(url, function(data){
             $('#'+j).html(data);
             j++;
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: А как некоректно?

Comment: нужно синхоронное выполнение - делай синхронный запрос.... но ajax на то и создавался, чтобы не быть синхроннным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что код внутри `$.get` будет выполнятся после всех `each`. Т.к. неизвестно заранее в каком порядке придут ответы то невозможно заранее предугадать значение `j` в каждом запросе.

Для того чтоб было последовательное выставление `$('#'+1)`, `$('#'+2)`, `$('#'+3)`, нужно сохранить значение `j` где нить в локальном замыкании внутри `each` (чтобы каждый вызов `each` сохранял свой `j`).

Так должно работать:

```
var url;
var id;
var j=1;


$(document).ready(function () {
$('div[data-loader]').each(function() {
    url=$(this).attr("data-loader");
    id=$(this).attr("id");  
    var tmp_j = j++;
    $.get(url, function(data){
          $('#'+tmp_j).html(data);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Это правильный ответ.